# How to check if a specific user is logged-in in firebase reatime database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Before explaining my question I just want to tell you that I know there is a function exist to check if a user is logged-in or not using this function:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) { ... };
```

But my requirement is a bit different, I am working on realtime chat app and for that I am using react and firebase. In this app I want to show the status (user is available or not), just like Facebook do. So for that what comes in my mind is, if there is some way to get the list of logged-in users in my firebase db or if there is some way to check if the user is logged-in by using email then my purpose will be solved.

So please let me know if there are some method exists or guide me some way by which I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Down-voters please mention the reason

Answer (score 1):

Auth States depend on variety of factors, like if the user gets disconnected from the internet for a long time. He would essentially be 'logged in' to the app (firebase remembers login) but he won't be active.

The best way moving forward is to check the last active time + disconnection with database. Firebase has a detailed documentation on [preference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence).

Comment: That make sense, I will try this solution. Thanks bro